# go build multiple binary versions each against a different shared library

Tags: go

I want to create a go executable which communicates with xen through it's native interface. There is a C shared library (actually 2) for this purpose and I created a simple go wrapper with cgo.

The problem is that I want to target 3 xen versions (3.2, 3.4, 4.0), each of which has a different shared library. The library itself provides basically the same API, but the sizes and shape of the structs defined in the C header are different, and thus the same compiled go binary cannot be used with these different shared libraries.

I want to have a go binary holding the 'main' and a go pkg which is the wrapper for xen.

I was thinking about 2 solutions:

1. I could build 3 different versions of the compiled pkg and also 3 different versions of the main binary each linked with the corresponding pkg version.  This solution requires building manually the makefiles so that I can pass the correct paths etc
2. I could build a thin C wrapper as a shared library and build it in 3 versions against the 3 versions of xen C bindings. This C wrapper would then export a stable C interface which is then used by one single go pkg. Then I can deploy the correct C wrapper shared library to the hosts and have it resolve at runtime

Is there any other way to handle that ? I would prefer using pure (c)go code but I don't like the additional burden of maintaining complicated makefiles.

EDIT: More details about why I feel uncomfortable about handling that manually in the makefiles:

For example the name of the _obj dir is hardcoded in Make.inc and company, and these makefiles rely on some generated .c files containing special information about the name of the shared library, which I have to cleanup before building the next version of the pkg. A snipped of my makefile:

```
all:
    rm -f _obj/_*
    $(MAKE) -f Makefile.common XENVERSION=3.0
    rm -f _obj/_*
    $(MAKE) -f Makefile.common XENVERSION=3.4
    rm -f _obj/_*
    $(MAKE) -f Makefile.common XENVERSION=4.0
```

where Makefile.common basically is a normal pkg makefile which uses `TARG=$(XENVERSION)/vimini/xen`, as I cannot encode the version in the package name because I'd have to modify the imports in the source.

By encoding the version in the package directory I can use `GCIMPORTS=-I../../pkg/xen/_obj/$(XENVERSION)` to select the right une from the main cmd's Makefile.

Of course I could roll out my own makefile which invokes 6c and 6l, cgo etc, but I prefer to leverage the existing make infrastructure since it seems that there is some wisdom in it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this approach?

[Architecture- and operating system-specific code](http://golang.org/doc/code.html#arch_os_specific)

It could easily be adapted to use a $XENVER environment variable.

Comment: Yes, I used a similar approach the problem is that I have to maintain my own makefiles and do some other tricks.